# Why is the DDR termination voltage half the supply voltage?

Tags: signal-integrity, termination, ddr, ddr3, ddr2

Why is the DDR termination voltage (VTT) one-half the VDD voltage?

Comment: Please can you edit your question and explain why VDD/3 or VDD/4. Have you read up on SSTL, which is specified in those SDRAM datasheets? There's application notes available explaining its function and of VTT - have you read any of those?

Comment: I edited the question.What I understood is it is kept at half to reduce power dissipation

Comment: Have a look at: https://training.ti.com/active-vs-passive-ddr-termination

Comment: Thanks. But have you looked for and read the SSTL info and app notes, as asked above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "termination voltage" in terms of Data/Adr/Clk lines connecting to the module/chip there are the following reasons:

The track has a capacitance. You either charge it to VCC or GND  (1/0) depending on your signal. So by biasing it to VCC/2 you get faster bit-times in both cases as the capacitance "is precharged" in case of a rising edge (from idle so VCC/2 to VCC).

You could ask: But if i want to charge it to GND this will cost extra time - this observation is correct. But, as you will also have to transmitt 1s you will be slower in this case. And access-time is based on wort-case timing -> So by precharging you get a speed improvement (higher clock rates possible).

If you mean "termination voltage" in terms of individual RAM-Cell biasing before readout: The "capacitor" storing the data-bit will be connected to some read-out logic in case of read-out. The Capacitor can hold 1 or 0 - so to faster get a stable voltage in the readout logic, the lines are precharged to 1/2 :) before detructive-readout.